# Android. Установка даты в DatePicker

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!

Использую DatePicker. Необходимо задать границы для даты(Это удается с помощью **setMinDate** и **setMaxDate**). А как установить нужную дату?

Answer (score 1):

[public void init (int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth, DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener onDateChangedListener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#init(int, int, int, android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener))

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }
}
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html - туториал по пикеру.

Comment: @Deadkenny я использую не DatePickerDialog, а просто элемент DatePicker. Поэтому соответственно onCreateDialog не уместен

Comment: @Мария_1 ну а как насчет метода init?

Comment: @Deadkenny к сожалению, он не срабатывает... я не знаю почему

Comment: @Мария_1 осталось только это http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#updateDate(int, int, int)

Comment: @Deadkenny Это тоже не сработало. Причем я в одном и том же месте устанавливаю текущее время TimePicker'у и дату DatePicker'у. Но последнему задать значения не удается :(

Answer (score -2):

попробуйте так

```
package jat.examples.DatePicker;

import jat.jdatepicker.JDateComponentFactory;

import jat.jdatepicker.JDatePicker;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class DatePickerExample extends JApplet{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1920676464239324135L;

JDatePicker depart_date_picker;

public void init() {

    depart_date_picker = JDateComponentFactory.createJDatePicker();
    depart_date_picker.setTextEditable(true);
    depart_date_picker.setShowYearButtons(true);

    add((JComponent) depart_date_picker);

}

public void start() {

    depart_date_picker.getModel().setYear(2010);
    depart_date_picker.getModel().setMonth(1);
    //depart_date_picker.getModel().setMonth(1);
    depart_date_picker.getModel().setDay(15);
    depart_date_picker.getModel().setSelected(true);    
}

}
```

Comment: но это не правильный ответ, вопрос по android